# Como inserir um campo em um documento no Firebase pelo código Ionic Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic, firebase, firebase-database

Não estou conseguindo inserir um campo com o id do usuario em um documento, preciso que o user.uid vire um campo do tipo boolean

Tentei isso, mas dá erro no ponto:

```
let{
user.uid : true
}
```

Também tentei adicionar o `user.uid` a uma variável antes, mas ele inseriu o nome da variável.

Comment: coloca o codigo completo que você está usando pra podermos ajudar melhor, provavelmente o user não tem uid por isso o erro, tente fazer um console.log(JSON.stringify(user)) pra ver o que tem nesse user